# How to open a project in read-only mode?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I manage a lot of similar projects with PhpStorm and it's easy to make changes to the wrong one.

I haven't the opportunity to manage file systems. Currently, I'm using git, and I'm always rolling back changes done on the wrong project. I don't lose data, but I'm still losing my time. It isn't a good enough solution.

Does anyone know if there is a way to open a project in PhpStorm in read-only mode?

Comment: Not a solution .. but some helpful thingy: define a custom scope and include ALL files in a project there. Now go to File Colors and create a rule for that scope and give a noticeable color (e.g. RED). If you now open a file .. it will have editor tab in that color .. plus any file tree will have it .. so it's more easier to recognize "this is not meant to be edited" project. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-file-colors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such option in IDE at this moment. You can vote for a corresponding feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-4178 to increase its priority.

Comment: Argh! This issue exists since 15 years. Thanks a lot Ástþór. I upvoted. If nobody purposes a tips I will validate this answer.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this one didn't get much attention lately. Probably a comment could refresh its status?

Comment: Done! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-4178